# How can set dynamically path importResource, based on application.properties file?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have this importResource `@ImportResource({"classpath:spring/*/*.xml"})`

I would set this path basing on value in application.properties file

I can pass dev or prod and the path should be `classpath:spring/dev/*.xml` or `classpath:spring/prod/*.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

in `application.properties`

```
my_profile=dev
```

Then add the string parameter to the annotation:

```
@ImportResource({"classpath:spring/${my_profile}/*.xml"})
```

You might also want to look how profiles are configured in spring: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html